# CorruptedFrame exception , websockets in Netty

Tags: java, netty

I was just playing around the websocket example client and server on netty wiki.
I modified the way server sends data to client.
Suddenly i started getting exception like "io.netty.handler.codec.CorruptedFrameException: bytes are not UTF-8"

This is on client and i am creating  frame on server like this :-

```
ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.buffer();
buf.writeShort(1);
channel.write(new TextWebSocketFrame(buf))
```

I understand from error that bytebuf must be UTF-8 encoded  , even the constructor of TextWebSocketFrame says this.
But i have no clue on why i am getting this error.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this as you try to send non UTF-8 data. If you want to just send any binary data use a BinaryWebSocketFrame.

Comment: Thanks Norman .. Was just wondering then what will be the use case of calling new TextWebSocketFrame(ByteBuf buf ) ?

Comment: You may already have UTF-8 data encoded in a ByteBuf. That is what it is useful for.